# Access webcam over internet using Python

Tags: python, webcam

I have written a program using Python and OpenCV where I perform operations on a video stream in run time. It works fine. Now if I want to publish it on a website where someone can see this using their browser and webcam, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really sure what you want to happen but if your going to implement this kind of feature in a website I think you should use a flash application instead of python (or if possible html 5). though your using python on the development of you web app it would only run on the server side instead and the feature you want to use is on a client side so for me it's more feasible to use flash instead to capture the video then after capturing the video you upload it to your server then your python code will do the rest of the process on the server side.